# Selenium: verifying contents of table

Tags: class, selenium, xpath, html-table

I have a simple problem.

I have:

```
   <td class="xxx">200</td> 
   <td class="xxx">200</td>
   <td class="yyyy">100</td>
   <td class="yyyy">100</td>
```

in my html.

Whats the best and nonintrusive way to make sure all the results of class "xxx" is 200 and all the results of class "yyyy" is 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use**:

```
  not('200' != //td[@class = 'xxx'])
and
  not('100' != //td[@class = 'yyyy'])
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select=
  "  not('200' != //td[@class = 'xxx'])
    and
      not('100' != //td[@class = 'yyyy'])
  "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document** (your fragment wrapped into a top element to become a well-formed XML document):

```
<t>
   <td class="xxx">200</td>
   <td class="xxx">200</td>
   <td class="yyyy">100</td>
   <td class="yyyy">100</td>
</t>
```

**produces**:

```
true
```

**When applied on this XML document**:

```
<t>
   <td class="xxx">200</td>
   <td class="xxx">200</td>
   <td class="yyyy">100</td>
   <td class="yyyy">101</td>
   <td class="yyyy">100</td>
</t>
```

**again the correct result is produced**:

```
false
```

**Explanation**:

Read about **[the XPath operator `!=`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#booleans)**.

Comment: How is this related to Selenium?

Comment: @psousa: This is "related to Selenium" the same way it is related to any other XPath engine: just evaluate the provided XPath expression with your XPath engine (in this case with Selenium).

Comment: The context here is end to end testing. Therefore, you shouldn't recommend an XPath to assert the rendered text since it could be not displayed, transformed or replaced by the shadow DOM.

Comment: @FlorentB. Different readers can interpret the question in different ways. The author of the question did accept this answer, and this means this answer solved his problem. Certainly, a **new**, related/similar question can be asked with emphasis on end-to-end testing and additional verification in the terms of object models used by the testing framework.

Comment: For an experienced tester, there's a single right way to interpret this question since Selenium is explicitly mentioned in the title. Even if it does seem to work, it doesn't mean that it will fulfill the expected objective. This answer doesn't qualify for a valid test and will lead other viewers to the wrong direction.

Comment: @FlorentB.I suggest that you provide your own question/answer in order to fix the perceived problem. This question was asked and answered almost six years ago, and it is inevitable that the focus/context/understanding/perception of the issue would have changed considerably during this long period. Do note that the author of the question tagged it as "XPath" and this clearly indicates his need of an XPath solution -- so such was provided and accepted. Again, other interpretations/needs may exist alongside this one -- these are best expressed as new questions.

Comment: Being from six years ago doesn't make it less wrong. Selenium uses XPath to locate an element so it's not unusual to see the tag and it doesn't mean that it should be used to validate some text.